# Status 200 ok giving blank response

Tags: spring

I am working on spring cloud project, getting status 200 ok status but the response body is empty for the APIs. Can any one help me to resolve the issue?

Thanks & Regards

Anita PAtil

Answer (score -1):

Status is different from the  Response vody. Response Body depends on what you are returning or binding any data to the Response Body. Know about HTTP Response status line, headers and  body and the difference between them. The status here Indicates that Server accepted the request or there is an aasociated action method in the server to respond.

Comment: I am working on microservice application every thing working fine, now the problem is when i do the proxy call from zuul to the microservices the data from microservice are coming as excepted but if I hit the url continuously getting the empty response..
What may be the reason for it?